# DVC checkout without Git

Tags: git, dvc

I am using [DVC](https://dvc.org/) for data version control in machine learning projects. Typically, switching between versions of data is managed to done by checkout `git` branches, commits, or tags to get appropriate `*.dvc` files that represent data checksum, then run `dvc checkout` to update data, for example:

```
git checkout ddc5c395b2afb2b2a626c62ef63a2c7d85382aa6 # to rollback to an old version of *.dvc files
dvc checkout mydata.dvc # to roll `mydata` back to the previous version
```

I now want to use DVC and switch between data versions without using `git`, what i am expecting is somethings like following:

```
dvc checkout mydata.dvc --tag v1.0
```

Could someone please guide me to use `dvc` in such a way? Thank you for any help.

Comment: A somewhat related CLI (and API) is `dvc get` - https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/get#get . E.g this example https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/get#example-compare-different-versions-of-data-or-model .

Answer (score 4):

To follow up on @omessor's comment, there are Python packages that allow you to programmatically work with a git repo (without using CLI git). DVC itself uses both [dulwich](https://github.com/jelmer/dulwich/tree/master/dulwich) and [pygit2](https://www.pygit2.org/) via [scmrepo](https://github.com/iterative/scmrepo).

You could actually do what you are looking for directly through DVC's internal API like

```py
from dvc.repo import Repo

dvc = Repo("path/to/your/repo")
dvc.scm.checkout("tags/v1.0")  # git checkout tags/v1.0
dvc.checkout("mydata.dvc")  # dvc checkout mydata.dvc
```

This would only require installing DVC via pip or conda, and does not require a CLI `git` installation.

Just note that these API's aren't publicly documented, so you may need to take a look at the DVC and scmrepo source to see how it works

https://github.com/iterative/dvc/blob/main/dvc/scm.py

Comment: Looks potential. Will mark this answer later if it works. Thank you sir.

Comment: Hi @pmrowla, your suggestion is exactly what I am looking for, appreciate your help, it saves my day. However, I can only upvote this answer, not marked it as accepted because it does not match the ultimate goal of the question fully. Once again, thank you.

Comment: Hi @pmrowla, if my dvc remote locates on a ssh server. How should I init and connect to the repo with dvc.repo.Repo?

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to achieve is not possible with DVC alone. As you demonstrated, one of DVC's functionalities is to help bring data management **into** existing VCS (like Git or SVN) so it manages manifests that are easily version controlled as text, and then, you can version them together with your code easily (using the dvc files as placeholder or indirections for your actual data).

DVC does not implement a complete Version Control System on its own (it does not create/manage refs/commits or tags).

I wonder why are you trying to break away from Git while still getting version control functionality. For example, if you are only managing data, it's perfectly acceptable to have a very lightweight git repo, only containing DVC artifacts, so you would get a small repo and the behavior you want from git+dvc without much "cost".

Then you would have something like the following, instead of the command you listed:

```bash
$ git checkout tags/v1.0
$ dvc checkout mydata.dvc
```

It should even be pretty easy to wrap git+dvc coupled commands in some lightweight wrapper or script if you want to avoid the extra typing.

EDIT: This answer relates to using DVC as CLI only. Seems like [@TaGuangTu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8531215/taquangtu) looked for code usage and avoiding using Git CLI specifically. [pmrowla's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76199391/1875031) answers that exactly

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. The reason why i want to use DVC alone is that I want to use DVC programmatically, for example running dvc commands to manage data versions with `subprocess` library in Python. Involving `Git` here makes things more complicated. Any idea to solve it?

Comment: edit: moved this comment into an answer since you can't have formatted code blocks in comments

Comment: Thanks for the answer [@pmrowla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1538451/pmrowla) - `dvc.scm` to the rescue!
His answer seems to be what OP looked for. I'll edit the above to clarify the answer is referring to CLI only